# TinyMCE v4 : TypeError: this.getDoc(…) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I got a very strange behaviour of tinyMCE, could you explained that?

**This work:**

```
tinymce.init({selector: '.textarea-tinymce'});
alert(tinymce.get(idTextarea));
var tinyMCEInstance = tinymce.get(idTextarea);
tinyMCEInstance.setContent('ok');
```

**This not work with error:** TypeError: this.getDoc(...) is undefined

```
tinymce.init({selector: '.textarea-tinymce'});
/*alert(tinymce.get(idTextarea));*/
var tinyMCEInstance = tinymce.get(idTextarea);
tinyMCEInstance.setContent('ok');
```

I don't want to put an alert to make my tinyMCE.setContent('ok') work... How an alert could be make tinyMCE work? What's the problem ??

Thank you for help !